# Type Error google.visualization.DataTable is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, html, google-apis-explorer, jsapi

I am trying to create a table using google chart, but it is returning the error of the contruct of the table method. I saw several references, but I think the error is something that is giving in the jsapi library, so google is not defining.

```
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot redefine property: Map
    at defineProperty (<anonymous>)
    at gvjs_bc (jsapi_compiled_format_module.js:13)
    at jsapi_compiled_format_module.js:28
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Xc' of undefined
    at jsapi_compiled_default_module.js:33
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'google' in undefined
    at gvjs_k (jsapi_compiled_format_module.js:33)
    at jsapi_compiled_bar_module.js:17
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'google' in undefined
    at gvjs_k (jsapi_compiled_format_module.js:33)
    at jsapi_compiled_table_module.js:5
 > Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: google.visualization.DataTable is not a constructor
    at drawChartUsersActive (UsersActive:280)
    at drawCharts (UsersActive:276)
    at loader.js:248
```

This is my html code, as you can see it is very simple, I'm just trying to plot the table, but always returns me these errors

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <meta name="layout" content="bootstrap">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="cabecalho"></div>
    <div id="table_div"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {
        packages: ['bar', 'corechart', 'table'],
        callback: drawCharts
      });

      function drawCharts() {
        drawChartUsersActive();
      }

      function drawChartUsersActive() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Salary');
        data.addColumn('boolean', 'Full Time Employee');
        data.addRows([
          ['Mike',  {v: 10000, f: '$10,000'}, true],
          ['Jim',   {v:8000,   f: '$8,000'},  false],
          ['Alice', {v: 12500, f: '$12,500'}, true],
          ['Bob',   {v: 7000,  f: '$7,000'},  true]
        ]);

        var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));

        table.draw(data, {showRowNumber: true, width: '100%', height: '100%'});
      }
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to replace:

```
google.charts.load('current', {
    packages: ['bar', 'corechart', 'table'],
    callback: drawCharts
  });

  function drawCharts() {
    drawChartUsersActive();
  }
```

by:

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['table']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChartUsersActive());
```

It's just what is written in the doc, so maybe it works ;)